# Jquery - returning value from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, selectable

Jfiddle containing my full attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/MdWDP/

As you can see I arranged some text/numbers in an array.

I want to use that as the return value instead of "index+1"

```
$("#selectable").selectable({

    selected: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.selected).addClass("ui-selected").siblings().removeClass("ui-selected");
        var labelArr = new Array("Name?", "Date?", "Else", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "50", "75", "100");
        var result = $("#select-result").empty();
        $(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {
            var index = $("#selectable li").index(this);
            result.append(index + 1);
            $("#description-name").val(labelArr[ui.value]);
            $("#test").val(index + 1);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The return value of what?

Comment: @ExplosionPills like currently it returns "index + 1" so if I pick <li> #5 it will return 5, so I thought I can make an array and just do Array[index+1] to get the 5th value from the array and return it

Comment: `ui.value`  is `undefined` so `labelArr[ui.value]` would also return `undefined`, thats why `#description-name` would not change at all, but you also you use `val()` instead of `text()` (If that is what you asking for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach at this line is wrong:

```
$("#description-name").val(labelArr[ui.value]);
```

It should be

```
$("#description-name").html(labelArr[index]);
```

`<span>` element doesn't have `$.fn.val` method in jQuery. [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/) says:
*The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea*

Also, `ui.value` in your code is `undefined`.

So, [here's your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MdWDP/3/).

Comment: Thanks I had it as .val(labelArr[index+1]) before but I saw my older script using ui.value thought it was some special variables thanks

Comment: Does my answer resolve your problem? If so, please be that kind and accept it.